# How to increase twilio recording time more than 10 hours?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am working in twilio call recording. Is there any option to record a call continuously for more than 10 hrs. Please advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The maximum length of a recording for a call on Twilio is 4 hours.

If you have exceptional need for this, I recommend you [get in touch with support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) to describe why you need such long calls and see if they can help you out.